# Why did Sci Hub stop uploading papers?

Tags: sci-hub

I looked at the most recent metadata (actually a compressed list of the DOIs of some 88 million publications) from the Sci-Hub project. None of the DOIs appear to be from later than 2021.

I can understand why Sci-Hub might choose, or be involuntarily forced, to close down ... but the choice to leave it online but in a frozen historical state seems unusual. What has happened in the legal, or domain registration space that would have motivated the choice?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with library GEnesis ? https://librarygenesis.net/

Comment: I believe there are no post-2021 papers on Library Genesis either

Comment: Answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/scihub/comments/lofj0r/announcement_scihub_has_been_paused_no_new/

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, you could probably develop that into an answer.

Comment: @Buffy Questions should show research effort if they can be answered with a simple Google search.